# Android Button Listerners

Tags: android, layout, button, tablelayout, onclicklistener

I am fairly new to this Android application thing and have a couple questions involving onclick listeners.

Right now I have a table inside a ScrollView with one column that includes several buttons.
My goal is to get to a point where I can click on a button and then a second table would come up right next to the first (same layout as the first) but with a different set of buttons. Can someone please guide me in the right direction.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation='vertical' >

 <ScrollView 
 android:layout_width="125dp" 
 android:layout_height="200dp"   >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table_right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:textSize="20dp" >   
             </Button>
           </TableRow>

         <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 2"
                    android:textSize="25dp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

         <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button_3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 3"
                    android:textSize="25dp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow> 

         <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button_4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 4"
                    android:textSize="25dp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

          <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button_5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 5"
                    android:textSize="25dp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

          <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button_6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 6"
                    android:textSize="25dp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>  
        </LinearLayout> 
            </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes please list your code so we can help you

Comment: set tag for the button and handle it.

Comment: I added what I had so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to toggle the table between visible and invisible will i'll recommend you to use this follow here my example :-

```
            boolean visible = true;
        private void showHide() {

            if (visible) {
            if(table1.getVisibility() == View.Invisible ); { 
                 table1.setVisibility(View.Visible) 
            }   
            }else table1.setVisibility(View.Invisible);

            visible = !visible;
        }
```

and on your `button` .`setOnClickListener` add `showHide();` now when you click the button it will show  `table1` and when you click it again it will hide it. hope that helped you.

Comment: This is java ?? Under android platoform.

Answer (score 1):

In the layout XML file, create both tables... but set the second table's visibility to "GONE". A visibility of GONE means that it won't even take any space in the layout.

I'm assuming you know how to execute some code when a button is pressed (if not, look up onclicklistener or the android:onClick xml shortcut). When the appropriate button is pressed, set the second table's visiblity to VISIBLE and it'll appear.

Comment: So I would be possible for a table to be visible and gone with a onclicklisterner

Comment: Would there be a way to dim the first table and leave the second standing out